# Getting ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict

Tags: python-2.7, kombu

I am getting the error

> ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict

while installing a server locally on my ubuntu 14.04 machine.
I have tried installing ordereddict manually and also tried upgrading kombu but it is still giving the error.The full traceback is added below-

> rishav@Swastik:~/open-event-orga-server$ sudo python create_db.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "create_db.py", line 5, in 
>       from app import current_app
>     File "/home/rishav/open-event-orga-server/app/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>       from celery import Celery
>    
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/**init**.py", line 133, in 
>       
> from celery import five  # noqa
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/five.py", line 153, in 
>       from kombu.utils.compat import OrderedDict  # noqa
>   ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solved my problem:

1. Downgraded kombu to 2.5.16.
2. Reinstalled django-celery

here is log:

```
(virtualEnv) D:\Project\staging\modone\settings>pip install django-celery
Collecting django-celery
  Downloading django_celery-3.2.1-py2-none-any.whl (63kB)
    100% |################################| 71kB 83kB/s
Collecting django>=1.8 (from django-celery)
  Using cached Django-1.10.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting celery<4.0,>=3.1.15 (from django-celery)
  Downloading celery-3.1.25-py2.py3-none-any.whl (526kB)
    100% |################################| 532kB 122kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>dev in d:\project\installations\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from celery<4.0,>=3.1.15->django-celery)
Collecting kombu<3.1,>=3.0.37 (from celery<4.0,>=3.1.15->django-celery)
  Using cached kombu-3.0.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting billiard<3.4,>=3.3.0.23 (from celery<4.0,>=3.1.15->django-celery)
  Downloading billiard-3.3.0.23-cp27-none-win32.whl (102kB)
    100% |################################| 102kB 114kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: anyjson>=0.3.3 in d:\project\installations\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (from kombu<3.1,>=3.0.37->celery<4.0,>=3.1.15->
django-celery)
Collecting amqp<2.0,>=1.4.9 (from kombu<3.1,>=3.0.37->celery<4.0,>=3.1.15->django-celery)
  Using cached amqp-1.4.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django, amqp, kombu, billiard, celery, django-celery
  Found existing installation: Django 1.4.5
    Uninstalling Django-1.4.5:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-1.4.5
  Found existing installation: amqp 1.0.13
    Uninstalling amqp-1.0.13:
      Successfully uninstalled amqp-1.0.13
  Found existing installation: kombu 2.5.16
    Uninstalling kombu-2.5.16:
      Successfully uninstalled kombu-2.5.16
  Found existing installation: billiard 2.7.3.28
    Uninstalling billiard-2.7.3.28:
      Successfully uninstalled billiard-2.7.3.28
  Found existing installation: celery 3.0.18
    Uninstalling celery-3.0.18:
      Successfully uninstalled celery-3.0.18
Successfully installed amqp-1.4.9 billiard-3.3.0.23 celery-3.1.25 django-1.10.5 django-celery-3.2.1 kombu-3.0.37
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem on python 2.7.8 with kombu 4.0.x and I solved it by downgrading kombu to 3.0.x (which was the version I needed).

Didn't have time to investigate the reason of the issue, but [this](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/632) might be related...

Answer (score 3):

The `ImportError` would also occur, if it is not correctly imported (such as with `orderedDict`, `Ordereddict`, or `ordereddict`):

#### Method 1

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

# dictionary sorted by key
print(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])))
print(OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)]))
```

#### Method 2

```
import collections

d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

# dictionary sorted by key
print(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])))
print(collections.OrderedDict(
    [('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)]))
```

#### Output

```
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

#### Source

[8.3.5.1. OrderedDict Examples and Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes)