# ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict; downgrade kombu

Tags: python-2.7, kombu

I am trying to install and import pytplot, which is a package that can plot IDL save files using python. I have Python 2.7 on Windows 10. If I try importing pytplot, I get an import error saying: ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict. This question has already been answered here: [Getting ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417647/getting-importerror-cannot-import-name-ordereddict).

However, I can't figure out how to complete the first step: downgrade kombu to the 2.5.16 version. I have uninstalled my current version of kombu and I'm trying to use:
    "pip install kombu-2.5.16"
This fails and my prompt says that it could not find a version that satisfies this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try: 
     `pip install -U kombu==2.5.16`
otherwise `pip -U kombu==3.5.x`
will show you all available versions